# JOIN with subquery - Syntax Problems SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, join, syntax

I want to find the most repeated value in a column named w.toy_id, given that it relates to another column named ch.child_id. 
That's why I have made it inside the JOIN and not in the place of dream_toy, but now it gives me the ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "w"'.

I am new to SQL so I apologize if it is a stupid question, but I have been going on for hours with this and I am desperate.

Anyone can help me?

```
FOR setof IN
      SELECT ch.child_id,ch.child_name, ch.city
            ,SUM(l.number_toys)
            ,COUNT (l.letter_id)
            ,MAX(l.number_toys),
            ,dream_toy
      FROM (CHILD ch LEFT JOIN LETTER l ON ch.child_id=l.child_id) 
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT w.toy_id
                       FROM WISHED_TOY w
                       GROUP BY w.toy_id
                       ORDER BY COUNT(w.toy_id) 
                       LIMIT 1) dream_toy ON (w.letter_id=l.letter_id)
      GROUP BY ch.child_id
      ORDER BY -SUM(l.number_toys) ASC, ch.child_name ASC 
      LIMIT 10
LOOP
    RETURN NEXT setof;
END LOOP
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: could you share a simple example with the desired output?

Comment: sample data please. what you have and what you want in resultset.

Comment: What does limit 10 do? That doesn't seem to be part of the requirement. Anyway, for further assistance, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

If I just take the query, you need to name the subquery feeding your main query (l1) and you need to use "dream_toy" in your join because that's how you named it. I've only made a few changes that needed to be done but you'll see the point.

```
 SELECT ch.child_id,ch.child_name, ch.city
        ,SUM(l.number_toys)
        ,COUNT (l.letter_id)
        ,MAX(l.number_toys),
        ,dream_toy
  FROM (CHILD ch LEFT JOIN LETTER l ON ch.child_id=l.child_id) as l1
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT w.toy_id
                   FROM WISHED_TOY w
                   GROUP BY w.toy_id
                   ORDER BY COUNT(w.toy_id) 
                   LIMIT 1) dream_toy ON (dream_toy.letter_id=l1.letter_id)
  GROUP BY ch.child_id
  ORDER BY -SUM(l.number_toys) ASC, ch.child_name ASC 
  LIMIT 10
```